# Unable to connect to Postgres SQL, using Jmeter JDBC connection

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jmeter

I'm unable to connect to postgressql using Jmeter JDBC connection, as I'm facing an issue with my cliet certificates I get this error:

> "java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could
>   not open SSL root certificate file ‪C:/path.ca.cert.der.)"

I've some client certificate under JDBC connection URL I just passed the cert path

I tried all the possible ways to add these certs under Lib/Ext/Bin

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace and the JDBC url you used.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51291765/root-crt-not-found-postgresql

Comment: @MarkRotteveel hey Mark here is the URL which I've used, jdbc:postgresql://mydomain.com:5432/item?ssl=true&sslmode=verify-ca&sslcompression=0&sslrootcert=‪C:/path.ca.cert.der&sslcert=‪‪C:/path.cert.der&sslkey=‪‪C:/path.pk8&sslpassword=password, however Im unable to get the full stack trace.. Once I get that I'll post this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding information in the comments and make sure to include the full exception stacktrace. Do the files you specify actually exist?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel -- Yes Mark, all the files exists, I'm trying to get full stack trace.